# Change Binding at runtime and save class instance WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am writing a WPF program write a program on .NET 4.5 which will hold a lot of settings inside and I am faced with several problems.

For example, I have a camera and I need to create another instance of that camera settings at runtime. For XAML page I have a lot of bindings and now for the second instance I need to clear them an use bindings for new instance of that class in which I hold properties for that settings (If I am thinking correctly, of course) So, I have 2 questions:

1. How do I change my binding so that I can write the minimum amount of code possible (please, keep in mind that I don't know how many instances will be created)?
2. How I can create second, third, etc. instances of a class and to lose objects in memory because I need to hold every instance of each class during runtime and just change bindings while switching between these instances.

Comment: Post your current code and XAML.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view model that manages and exposes the settings for you. Use an additional property to provide the currently selected settings:

```
public class CameraSettings
{
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public bool Grayscale { get; set; }
}

public class CameraViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private CameraSettings _SelectedSettings;
  private List<CameraSettings> _Settings;

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  public IEnumerable<CameraSettings> Settings
  {
    get { return _Settings; }
  }

  public CameraSettings SelectedSettings
  {
    get { return _SelectedSettings; }
    set
    {
      if (_SelectedSettings != value)
      {
        _SelectedSettings = value;

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
          PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectedSettings"));
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public CameraViewModel()
  {
    _Settings = new List<CameraSettings>()
    {
      { new CameraSettings() { Title = "BlackWhite", Grayscale = true } },
      { new CameraSettings() { Title = "TrueColor", Grayscale = false } }
    };
  }

}
```

Then you can bind your view to this view model. Example view:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:CameraViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>

    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Settings}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSettings, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Title}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedSettings.Grayscale}" />

</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I will just change datacontext of the page and use List<> for handling instances.